# How to translate property with params in choice_label from EntityType

Tags: php, symfony-3.4

I have a formtype with a field EntityType, this EntityType has a 'choice_label' with my property `'toStringToForm'` like this:

```
//My formtype
->add('entities',EntityType::class, array(
                'class' => 'EntidadBundle:Entity',
                'choice_label' => 'toStringToForm',
                'multiple' => true,
                'expanded' => true,
```

The property in my Entity has the following:

```
//My Entity
public function toStringToForm()
    {
        return "- Margarita ".$this->getMargarita()->getColor()." - Canister ".$this->getMargarita()->getCanister()->getCodigo()."- Color ".$this->getColor()." -";
    }
```

1. What is the best way to translate this property?

2. What is the best way to translate this property by declaring it in my translation file?

Answer (score 0):

I would say, the best way how to translate entities is to have the translations in the database. That means having join table like `entity_localize` or something like that to keep the names there (so that it is also easier to track and you don't keep that inside a files and DB at the same time)

In my opinion translation files are supposed to be used for "static" translations (field names, headers, etc.) and not for dynamic content that entities are.